# How can I catch QTreeView deselected event?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

How can I catch QTreeView deselected event?Is there in QT this type event?     Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[QAbstractItemView::selectionModel()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel) will return a pointer to the selection model of the view. That model [fires a signal](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectionChanged) whenever the selection is changed, whether it's selected or deselected.

Connect the `QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged(const QItemSelection & selected, const QItemSelection & deselected)` signal to a slot in your code, and deal with the `deselected` parameter.